# How to make springmessage with dynamic data inside

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Hi I want to add a dynamic parameter inside my spring:message.

Now I have that in my message.properties :

```
serviceModel.annualCharge=Guidelines 2013 Annual recharge
```

And in my code i call it like this :

```
<spring:message code="serviceModel.annualCharge" />
```

I want to have :

```
serviceModel.annualCharge=Guidelines (current year) Annual recharge
```

Is it possible ?

Regards

Comment: Have you read the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message)?

Comment: I read it but I don't really understand it, when I read i understand something like : serviceModel.annualCharge=Guidelines, (Mystring), Annual recharge

Comment: @M. Deinum I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder in your properties file like this

```
serviceModel.annualCharge=Guidelines {0} Annual recharge
```

and while invoking spring message tag, pass your dynamic value as argument

```
<spring:message code="serviceModel.annualCharge" arguments="${currentYear} />;
```

Hope this helps :)